# Simplify Sum of Hypergeometric Functions

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Write the following "sum" in terms of $\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$:

$$ _2 F_1(a,b+1;c+1;z) +\, _2 F_1(a,b-1;c-1;z) -\, _2 F_1(a,b;c;z).$$

Attempt: I played around with identities in [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/ShowAll.html).  In particular, to make necessary transformation, I had to take derivative w.r.t. $\,z\,$ at some point after which I would get additional functions which I had to convert again to $\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z).$

Comment: What makes you think that the expression can be simplified? What are you attempting to accomplish? In other words, what is the context here?